# mod_python and getting the QUERY_STRING using env_vars()

Tags: python, query-string, mod-python

I am having some problems with some code, trying to get the QUERY_STRING but when I look at the errors in the console its coming back with an internal Error 500 which seems to be caused by the line `getReqStr = env_vars['QUERY_STRING']`

Anyone any ideas how to fix this please?

```
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb
from urlparse import urlparse

def index(req):

    req.add_common_vars()
    env_vars = req.subprocess_env
    getReqStr = env_vars['QUERY_STRING']           
    getReqArr = getReqStr.split('&')               
    getReqDict = {}

    for item in getReqArr:                          
       tempArr = item.split('=')                    
       getReqDict[tempArr[0]] = tempArr[1]
 
    dtbox = getReqDict['dt']
    tmbox = getReqDict['tm']

    con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb')

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        st = "SELECT tmp, watts FROM currentcost WHERE dt ='" + dtbox + "' and tm like '" + tmbox + "%'"
        cur.execute (s)
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        x=""
        y=""
        for row in rows:
            x=x+row["watts"]+","
            y=y+row["tmp"]+","

    x="data:["+x+"]"
    y="data:["+y+"]"

    con.close()

    req.write(st)
```

EDIT.

Here is the response I'm getting back through Chrome's console:

MOD_PYTHON ERRORProcessId:      3424Interpreter:    '127.0.1.1'ServerName:     '127.0.1.1'DocumentRoot:   '/var/www'URI:            '/currentcost.py'Location:       NoneDirectory:      '/var/www/'Filename:       '/var/www/currentcost.py'PathInfo:       ''Phase:          'PythonHandler'Handler:        'mod_python.publisher'Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target    result = object(arg)  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 204, in handler    module = page_cache[req]  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1059, in **getitem**    return import_module(req.filename)  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 296, in import_module    log, import_path)  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 680, in import_module    execfile(file, module.**dict**)  File "/var/www/currentcost.py", line 17    getReqStr = env_vars['QUERY_STRING']           ' the url after the ?                                                                       ^SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literalMODULE CACHE DETAILSAccessed:       Thu Sep 26 09:18:30 2013Generation:     0_mp_545c0d0056a74a40503ad1da7dbb26e2 {  FileName:     '/var/www/currentcost.py'  Instance:     1 [IMPORT]  Generation:   0 [ERROR]  Modified:     Thu Sep 26 09:10:57 2013}

Comment: `QUERY_STRING` may not even exist in `env_vars` which probably raises a `KeyError` exception... can we have the full traceback ?

Comment: @Andre I've updated the post with the full trace

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `mod_python`, then [req.args](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pythonapi.html#apache.request.args) probably has all your data.

You can also get query_string using the `req.parsed_uri[apache.URI_QUERY]`

If you need to handle GET and POST without thinking about it, then you better parse it using [FieldStorage](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pythonapi.html#pyapi-util-fstor) class bundled with `mod_python`. Should be something like this:

```
from mod_python import util

getReqDict = util.FieldStorage(req)
dtbox = getReqDict['dt']
tmbox = getReqDict['tm']
```

As an additional observation of your code: the way you build your SQL query is not secure and vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).
Do not forget to escape your data before passing to SQL query, or use [query parameter binding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) (preferred method) instead.